# How to Collapse All / Expand All functions/methods in Codeblocks IDE

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, codeblocks

In the CodeBlocks IDE, you can click to the left of a function and minimize everything in that function. However, in IDEs such as IntelliJ, I can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> to Expand/Collapse All methods. Is there a similar shortcut in CodeBlocks?

Answer (score 6):

It's <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>.
It will toggle collapse on all the blocks.

Hope it helps.

Comment: That's actually a toggle, not a collapse all.

Comment: @EmadY correct, but even on 1000 lines of code, it is a very fast operation, so if the first toggle didn't collapse them, just click F12 again, and it will collapse :)

Answer (score 6):

There isn't one by default, but you can add it, just open:

`Settings -> Editor -> Keyboard Shortcuts -> Edit -> Folding -> Fold All` and now just set it .